# Split file basename by character

Tags: string, matlab, path

I have a tif file that I have defined in MATLAB:

```
f = 'C:\temp\buffers_41113034_nw.tif'
```

How can I extract a portion of the basename so that the format is as follows:

```
'41113034_nw.tif'
```

I know that I can get at the basename using the following approach--just not sure how to take a subset of the basename:

```
>> [pathstr,name,ext] = fileparts(f); 
>> [name ext]

ans =

buffers_41113034_nw.tif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of `strrep`(to remove the keyword `"buffers_"`) and `strcat` (to concatenate with the extension) -

```
strcat(strrep(name,'buffers_',''),ext)
```